# Change tracking lost on table design changes

Tags: t-sql, ssms

Using SQL Management Studio (the  latest version, with SQL Express), I enable [change tracking](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb964713.aspx) on a database and some of its tables.

If I ever need to edit the columns of one of this tables where change tracking is enabled, I will have to re-enable change tracking manually on this table afterward.

Is there any way to have change tracking automatically re-enabled after an edition to the table structure ?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think so, but if you can afford to lose some of the data you could set up a job to run periodically and re-enable it. You should also extract the CT data and archive it somewhere before you make the table change.